# VNC kicks out new user on Fedora 23 (113 Error)

Tags: fedora, vnc, users

I used the Fedora documentation located [here](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/21/html/System_Administrators_Guide/ch-TigerVNC.html) to set up a VNC server on a Fedora 23 and it works in single user mode. Now I am trying to set it up for multiple users. Right now the :1 display is being used and has no issues with authentication. The new user is on the :5 display and for test purposes I am using the same user as I did with display :1
Running systemctl status on both VNC services report no errors or warnings:

```
 vncserver-bkeys@:5.service - Remote desktop service (VNC)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/vncserver-bkeys@.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2016-03-02 22:03:28 EST; 44min ago
 Main PID: 1044 (Xvnc)
   CGroup: /system.slice/system-vncserver\x2dbkeys.slice/vncserver-bkeys@:5.service
           \u2023 1044 /usr/bin/Xvnc :5 -auth /home/bkeys/.Xauthority -desktop loc...

Mar 02 22:03:07 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Remote desktop ser...
Mar 02 22:03:28 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Remote desktop serv...
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

If I systemctl stop firewall then both users can connect so it should have to do with the firewall.
So how do I get the second display to work so that they can connect on their specified display?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem; it figures that VNC ports use a different port depending on which virtual display you are using so in my case I was trying to use display `:5` so I needed to have port `5905` public in the `firewalld`:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=5905/tcp
```

Hope someone finds this helpful